# Java - parsing a 2nd csv file to override a value

Tags: java, csv, arraylist

I have two csv files. One shows all crime data including City, State, Population etc. The other shows State and Abbreviation. I want to have the state set as the abbreviation, currently I have some very long code and I'm thinking there is definitely a better way at setting it based on the abbreviation csv file.

My main class:

```
    public class StartApp {

public static ArrayList<CityCrime> crimes = new ArrayList<CityCrime>();
public static ArrayList<String> cities = new ArrayList<String>(); 

/**
 * Start point for app. Directs the reads from file and shows the menu
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        readCrimeData("crimeUSA.csv");
        System.out.println("Total cities read: " + getTotalCities());
        showMenu();
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Reads the crime data for each city from entered file
 * Adds the CityCrime objects to the crimes ArrayList
 */
public static void readCrimeData(String fromFile) {

    File file = new File(fromFile);

    FileReader fileReader;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    String crimeInfo;
    String[] stats;

    try {
        fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        crimeInfo = bufferedReader.readLine();
        crimeInfo = bufferedReader.readLine();

        do {
            CityCrime crime = new CityCrime(); // Default constructor
            stats = crimeInfo.split(",");
            {
                if (stats[0] != null) {
                    crime.setCity(stats[0]);
                }
                if (stats[1] != null) {
                    crime.setState(stats[1]);
                }
                if (stats[2] != null) {
                    if (Integer.parseInt(stats[2]) >= 0) {
                        crime.setPopulation(Integer.parseInt(stats[2]));
                    }
                }
                if (stats[3] != null) {
                    if (Integer.parseInt(stats[3]) >= 0) {
                        crime.setMurder(Integer.parseInt(stats[3]));
                    }
                }

                if (stats[4] != null) {
                    if (Integer.parseInt(stats[4]) >= 0) {
                        crime.setRobbery(Integer.parseInt(stats[4]));
                    }
                }

                if (stats[5] != null) {
                    if (Integer.parseInt(stats[5]) >= 0) {
                        crime.setAssault(Integer.parseInt(stats[5]));
                    }
                }

                if (stats[6] != null) {
                    if (Integer.parseInt(stats[6]) >= 0) {
                        crime.setBurglary(Integer.parseInt(stats[6]));
                    }
                }

                if (stats[7] != null) {
                    if (Integer.parseInt(stats[7]) >= 0) {
                        crime.setLarceny(Integer.parseInt(stats[7]));
                    }
                }

                if (stats[8] != null) {
                    if (Integer.parseInt(stats[8]) >= 0) {
                        crime.setMotorTheft(Integer.parseInt(stats[8]));
                    }
                }
                crime.setTotalCrimes(Integer.parseInt(stats[3]), Integer.parseInt(stats[4]), Integer.parseInt(stats[5]), Integer.parseInt(stats[6]), Integer.parseInt(stats[7]), Integer.parseInt(stats[8]));
            }
            crimes.add(crime);
            System.out.println(crime);

            crimeInfo = bufferedReader.readLine();

        } while (crimeInfo != null);

        fileReader.close();
        bufferedReader.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

/**
 * For each crime, add the city to the cities ArrayList and return the count
 */
public static int getTotalCities() {
    for(CityCrime crime : crimes) {
        cities.add(crime.getCity());
    }
    int cityCount = cities.size();
    return cityCount;
}

/**
 * Displays the menu
 * User can select which function they want to run
 * @throws IOException 
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unlikely-arg-type")
public static void showMenu() throws IOException {

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner menuSelect = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("1. Display all crime stats by city");
    System.out.println("2. Display all crime stats by selected city");
    System.out.println("3. Display the murder stats by selected state ");
    System.out.println("4. Display  highest crime city - all crimes");
    System.out.println("5. Display each state (in alphabetical order with the number of car thefts ");
    System.out.println("6. Write / export all cities in descending order of Robbery rate ");
    System.out.println("7. Quit");
    System.out.println("Enter option 1-7");
    
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int option = Integer.parseInt(menuSelect.next());
    if(option<1 || option>7 ) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input.");
        return;
    }
    switch (option) {
    case 1:
        displayAllCityCrimeStats();
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("Enter city");
        String cityOption = menuSelect.next();
        displayCrimeStatsByCity(cityOption);
        break;
    case 3:
        System.out.println("Enter state");
        String stateOption = menuSelect.next();
        displayMurdersByState(stateOption);
        break;
    case 4:
        displayHighestCrimeStats();
        break;
    case 5:
        displayStateCarThefts();
        break;
    case 6:
        writeToFile("Robbery.csv");
        break;
    case 7:
        return; 
    default:
        option = Integer.parseInt(scanner.next());
    }

}
```

My CityCrime file. It is a mess right now as I don't know what the right direction to go in is. I have cut down the setStates, there are 52 in reality so it's pretty long:

```
    public class CityCrime {


//Instance variables
private String city;
private String state;
private int population;
private int murder;
private int robbery;
private int assault;
private int burglary;
private int larceny;
private int motorTheft;
public int totalCrimes;
public static ArrayList<CityState> abbreviations = new ArrayList<CityState>();
public String fromFile = ("C:/Users/ebeck/Downloads/StateAbbreviations.csv");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
}

public static void readAbbrevData(String fromFile) {

    File file = new File(fromFile);

    FileReader fileReader;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    String abbrevInfo;
    String[] stats;

    try {
        fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        abbrevInfo = bufferedReader.readLine();
        abbrevInfo = bufferedReader.readLine();

        do {
            CityState abbrev = new CityState(); // Default constructor
            stats = abbrevInfo.split(",");
            {
                if (stats[0] != null) {
                    abbrev.setState(stats[0]);
                }
                if (stats[1] != null) {
                    abbrev.setAbbreviation(stats[1]);
                }
            }
            abbreviations.add(abbrev);
            System.out.println(abbrev);

            abbrevInfo = bufferedReader.readLine();

        } while (abbrevInfo != null);

        fileReader.close();
        bufferedReader.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public String getState() {
    return state;
}

public void setState(String state) {
    if(state.equalsIgnoreCase("ALABAMA")) {
        this.state = "AL";
    }
    else if(state.equalsIgnoreCase("ALASKA")) {
        this.state = "AK";
    }
    else if(state.equalsIgnoreCase("ARIZONA")) {
        this.state = "AR";
    }
    else if(state.equalsIgnoreCase("ARKANSAS")) {
        this.state = "AR";
    }
    else if(state.equalsIgnoreCase("CALIFORNIA")) {
        this.state = "CA";
    }
    else if(state.equalsIgnoreCase("COLORADO")) {
        this.state = "CO";
    }
    else if(state.equalsIgnoreCase("CONNECTICUT")) {
        this.state = "CT";
    }
    //etc
}

public int getPopulation() {
    return population;
}


public void setPopulation(int population) {
    this.population = population;

}


public int getMurder() {
    return murder;
}
    //etc
```

}

I created a CityState file, however may be unnecessary:
public class CityState {

```
private String state;
private String abbreviation;



public static void main(String[] args) {
    
}

public String getState() {
    return state;
}

public String getAbbreviation() {
    return abbreviation;
}
public void setAbbreviation(String abbreviation) {
    this.abbreviation = abbreviation;
}

public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
    
}
```

}

A couple reasons I want to change how I've set up the get state is 1. for my Junit test for state:

```
        @Test
public void testValidState() {
    CityCrime crimes = new CityCrime();
    crimes.setState(state);
    assertEquals(crimes.getState(), state);     
}
```

I was getting the error:

expected: <A[K] but was: <A[LASKA]> if I set the state to "Alaska"

Then if I set it to "AK" I got the error:

expected: but was:

and 2. it doesn't look great either and I want to learn a better way

Thankyou for your help I appreciate it

Edit:
For each crime, if the state in CityCrimes csv file is equal to the state in the StatesAbbreviations file, then set the state as the abbreviation in the StatesAbbreviations file and return

Comment: First of all, can you give an example of your second CSV file? I dont understand why you have this file while you have harcoded this in the setState function.

Comment: The 2nd CSV file is headers State , Abbreviation, then eg Alaska , AL … New York, NY etc. It then says to shows the states as in abbreviation csv file. So from that i wasn’t sure how to hardcode it , or to read in that csv file. I went with the easier option at start, but would now like to improve my code and know how else I can do it :)

Comment: @Oromis , I've added a small comment in the end, hoping it makes more sense of what I want to do

Comment: not related to the question, but since you mentioned you'd want to see better ways, I would recommend you'd use a static Map<String, String> to get the abbreviations. Imagine you want to get to Wyoming, then you'd have to check 50 possibilities that come before it, while the Map can give you result instantaneously. `if(option<1 || option>7 )` I would move into the switch-case's `default` case. Also note that `do while` will always run at least once, so if crime info is null, you'll have a NPE anyway, `do while` simply can't be used to avoid NPEs (unless you check inside the loop again)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first of all, I think it's better to split the data from the data parsing.
One class = one representation. Here `CityCrime` has two goals: represent quantity of crimes in a City (the goal indicated by the class name) and parse the abbreviation list. So I think it's better to create a new class whose goal is the parsing of your abbreviations.

Next, there is a consistency problem: you have a function that parse your abbreviation CSV, but you have also a list of if to "convert" a state name to a state abbreviation (`setState` function). There is, according to me, two ways to do this:

- Define State as a type
- Define State as resource

### State as a type

The advantage of this method is to benefit from a strong typing. Indeed, with your `setState` solution, you define a State as a String, and you have to check if the passed value is correct (succession of if). Moreover, as it remains a String, you have no guarantee that the value returned by `getState` is formatted well (you have to trust all the functions that write on `state` variable).
So the solution here is to defined State as a type, using, for example, Enumeration.

```java
public enum State {
    ALABAMA("AL"),
    ALASKA("AK"),
    ARIZONA("AR"),
    ARKANSAS("AR"),
    CALIFORNIA("CA"),
    COLORADO("CO"),
    CONNECTICUT("CT");

    private String abbreviation;

    State(String abbreviation) {
        this.abbreviation = abbreviation;
    }

    public String getAbbreviation() {
        return abbreviation;
    }
}
```

An enum is a particular type of class. Indeed, this one is not direclty instanciable (you can't do `new State("foo")`). The accepted instances for this type are defined as an enumeration, at the start of the class (`ALABAMA`, `ALASKA`...). So `State.ALABAMA` has for type `State` and `State.ALABAMA.getAbbrevation()` returns `AL`.
This solution works only if the set of all your states is closed, so if your have a fixed number of state.

In this situation, your `state` variable would have for type `State`, and your `setState` function would take a State variable. This is strong typed, because you can't pass a value that is not valid to the function (except null).

> How to convert a State name to a State variable ?

Enumeration classes have a `valueOf(String name)` function. The parameter is the identifier of the enum constant (`ALABAMA`, `ALASKA`) as a String, and the returned value is the enum constant as State. If any enum constant was found, an IllegalArgumentException is throwed. This solution works well, but the string must correspond exactly to the identifier (case included).
If you want to do a similar function, but ignoring case, you can use `values` function that returns an array of all State values (`State[]`). For example:

```java
    public static State valueOfIgnoreCase(String name) {
        for(var state: State.values())
            if(state.name.equals(name)) // name function return the exact identifier of the state
                return state;
        return null; // Or throw IllegalArgumentException
    }
```

This function can be create in the `State` class.

### State as a resource

Another solution is to define State as a resource, that is, in an external file (or resource file). The advantage is you can add new State dynamically, without having to modify the program code. It's the solution you use with your parser.
For this solution, the parser is in a separated class.
Instead of put all your State in an List, you can put in a Map:

```java
public class AbbreviationParser {

 public static Map<String, State> parseState(InputStream stream) throws IOException { // InputStream is better than String or File, because it abstract the type of input (can works with a simple file, a network stream, a text downloaded from Internet...)
        final var map = new HashMap<String, State>();

        final var reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream)); // Define a reader on the stream then bufferize it for better performance
        reader.readLine();

        String line;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { // As long as there is an unread line
            var array = line.split(",");
            if(array.length == 2) {// Important, because if your line does not contain a comma, your actual code will crash at "array[1]"
                var state = new State();
                state.setState(array[0]);
                state.setAbbreviation(array[1]);
                map.put(state.getState(), state);
            } else {
                //TODO define a behavior if the line is not valid
            }
        }

        reader.close();
        stream.close();
        return map;
 }
```

To call this function for a File:

```java
parseState(new FileInputStream(fromFile)); // FileInputStream is an implementation of InputStream for File
```

To secure your State from external instantiation, you can put the State constructor in package-only scope, and place this class and AbbreviationParser in the same package. Like this, only the class on the same package (so AbbreviationParser) can instantiate State, and you are thus sure not to have an incorrect value passed to your `setState(State state)`:

```java
public class State {

    private String state;
    private String abbreviation;

    State() {}

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public String getAbbreviation() {
        return abbreviation;
    }
    public void setAbbreviation(String abbreviation) {
        this.abbreviation = abbreviation;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;

    }

}
```

Even if you prefer the first method for your State, I recommend you to take inspiration from my parser for your first CSV parser and to isolate it in a separated class.

Answer (score 0):

You want to replace certain values in the first CSV file with corresponding values in the second CSV file. The code will be extremely long if you use Java to perform the association.

But it is easy to do the coding job using Java’s open-source package SPL. One line of code is enough:

| + | 1 |
| --- | --- |
|  | =file("crimeUSA.csv").import@ct().switch(State,file("StateAbbreviations.csv").import@ct():State) .new(City,State.Abbreviation: StateAbbreviation,Population,Murder,Robbery,Assault,Burglary, Larceny,MotorTheft,TotalCrimes) |

SPL offers JDBC driver to be invoked by Java. Just store the above SPL script as abbr.splx and invoke it in Java as you call a stored procedure:

```
…    
Class.forName("com.esproc.jdbc.InternalDriver");
con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:esproc:local://");
st=con.prepareCall("call abbr()");
st.execute();
…
```

Or execute the SPL string within a Java program as we execute a SQL statement:

```
…    
st = con.prepareStatement("==file(\"crimeUSA.csv\").import@ct().
     switch(State,file(\"StateAbbreviations.csv\").import@ct():State)
     .new(City,State.Abbreviation,Population,Murder,Robbery,Assault
     ,Burglary,Larceny,MotorTheft,TotalCrimes)");

st.execute();  
…
```